# Odoo website, Creating a signup page for external users

Tags: python-2.7, odoo, odoo-9

How can I create a signup page in odoo website. The **auth_signup** module seems to do the job (according to their description). I don't know how to utilize it.

- In the signup page there shouldn't be database selector
- Where should I store the user data(including password); **res.users** or **res.partner**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. you can turn off db listing w/ some params in in odoo.cfg conf

   `db_name = mydb
   list_db = False
   dbfilter = mydb`
2. `auth_signup` takes care of the registration, you don't need to do anything. A res.user will be created as well as a partner related to it.
   The pwd is stored in the user.

Answer (score 1):

User Signup is a standard feature provided by Odoo, and it seems that you already found it.

The database selector shows because you have several PostgresSSQL databases.
The easiest way is to set a filter that limits it to the one you want:
start the server with the option `--dbfilter=^MYDB$`, where `MYDB`is the database name.

User data is stored both in `res.user`and `res.partner`: the user specific data, such as login and password, are stored in `res.user`. Other data, such as the Name is stored in a related `res.partner` record.